# Is there any way to refactor this code to improve the performace?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

So I have this issue for an exercise. The code works but I want to improve the performance of the code as such that there are no time complexity issues (no nested for loops for example). But I can't seem to find a way.

The task is to create a JavaScript selection engine, a function that will return DOM elements given a CSS selector. I cannot use any external libraries or document.querySelector/queryselectorAll.

The HTML body is this

```
 <body>
    <div></div>
    <div id="some_id" class="some_class some_other_class"></div>
    <img id="some_other_id" class="some_class some_other_class"></img>
    <input type="text">
</body>
```

My current solution is this

```
var $ = function (selector) {

    if (typeof selector !== "string"){
        throw TypeError("Please enter a selector in a string format")
    }

    let results = [];
    let classes = getClasses();

    let hasClass, hasID, str, a

    if (document.getElementsByTagName(selector)){
        hasClass = selector.includes(".") ? true : false
        hadID = selector.includes("#") ? true : false
    }


    if (hasClass && hasID) {

        let i = 0;
        while (i < classes.length){
            if (selector.includes(classes[i])) {
                str = classes[i];
                a = document.getElementsByClassName(str);

                if (selector.includes(a[i].id)) results.push(a[i]);
            }
            i++
        }

    } else if (hasClass) {

        let list1, list2;

        for (i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
            if (selector.includes(classes[i])) {
                str = classes[i];
                a = document.getElementsByClassName(str);

                for (j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                    if (selector.charAt(0) === ".") {
                        results.push(a[j]);
                    } else if (selector.includes(a[j].tagName.toLowerCase())) {
                        results.push(a[j]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } else if (hasID) {
        if (selector.charAt(0) === "#") results.push(window[selector.substring(selector.indexOf("#") + 1, selector.length)]);


    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) results.push(t[i]);
    }

    return results;
}




function getClasses(){

    let nodesArray = document.body.childNodes
    let results = [];

    i = 0;
    while (i < nodesArray.length){

        let element = nodesArray[i].nodeName;

        if (!element.includes("#")){
            for (j = 0; j < nodesArray[i].classList.length; j++) results.push(nodesArray[i].classList[j]);
        }
        i++

    }

    let x = Array.from(new Set(results))
    console.log(x)
    return x

}
```

The end results with examples should be

```
$("div") - Should return 2 DIVs 
$("img.some_class") - Should return 1 IMG 
$("#some_id") - Should return 1 DIV 
$(".some_class") - Should return 1 DIV and 1 IMG 
$("input#some_id") - Should return an empty array 
$("div#some_id.some_class") - Should return 1 DIV 
$("div.some_class#some_id") - Should return 1 DIV
```

Answer (score 1):

Elements have, built-in, a method allowing you to check if they match a particular selector: [`.matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches). It's much easier not to have to re-invent the wheel for an already solved problem. Get all elements in the document, then on each call of `$`, return an array of those elements filtered by whether they match the selector:

```js
const getAllChildren = (parent, results = []) => {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(
    parent.children,
    (child) => {
      results.push(child);
      getAllChildren(child, results);
    }
  );
  return results;
};
var $ = function (selector) {
  return getAllChildren(document.body)
    .filter(elm => elm.matches(selector));
}
console.log($("div")) // Should return 2 DIVs 
console.log($("img.some_class")) // Should return 1 IMG 
console.log($("#some_id")) // Should return 1 DIV 
console.log($(".some_class")) // Should return 1 DIV and 1 IMG 
console.log($("input#some_id")) // Should return an empty array 
console.log($("div#some_id.some_class")) // Should return 1 DIV 
console.log($("div.some_class#some_id")) // Should return 1 DIV
```

```html
<div></div>
<div id="some_id" class="some_class some_other_class"></div>
<img id="some_other_id" class="some_class some_other_class"></img>
<input type="text">
```

If you know in advance that no new nodes are going to be added or removed during a certain period, you can cache the children instead of re-retrieving them:

```js
const getAllChildren = (parent, results = []) => {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(
    parent.children,
    (child) => {
      results.push(child);
      getAllChildren(child, results);
    }
  );
  return results;
};
const allElements = getAllChildren(document.body);
var $ = function (selector) {
  return allElements.filter(elm => elm.matches(selector));
}
console.log($("div")) // Should return 2 DIVs 
console.log($("img.some_class")) // Should return 1 IMG 
console.log($("#some_id")) // Should return 1 DIV 
console.log($(".some_class")) // Should return 1 DIV and 1 IMG 
console.log($("input#some_id")) // Should return an empty array 
console.log($("div#some_id.some_class")) // Should return 1 DIV 
console.log($("div.some_class#some_id")) // Should return 1 DIV
```

```html
<div></div>
<div id="some_id" class="some_class some_other_class"></div>
<img id="some_other_id" class="some_class some_other_class"></img>
<input type="text">
```

Another option to avoid having to re-retrieve all elements when `$` is called would be to set a deep MutationObserver on the document, which will listen for added and removed nodes anywhere in the DOM, and then add / remove those from the collection. But, this method is expensive for large pages with frequent changes, and the MutationObserver callback will only run in a microtask, rather than synchronously.

If you need to cache the collection *and* update synchronously, you can watch for [`DOMNodeRemoved`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events) and `DOMNodeAdded` events, which are synchronous, but deprecated and not recommended.

Thanks to Kaiido's suggestion, you can also use a TreeWalker to get all descendant elements of a certain parent:

```js
var $ = function (selector) {
  const results = [];
  const treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
    document.body,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,
    // Works, but less efficient than checking inside the while loop below:
    // { acceptNode: node => node.matches(selector) ? NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT : NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT }
    null
  );
  while(treeWalker.nextNode()) {
    const node = treeWalker.currentNode;
    if (node.matches(selector)) {
      results.push(node);
    }
  }
  return results;
}
console.log($("div")) // Should return 2 DIVs 
console.log($("img.some_class")) // Should return 1 IMG 
console.log($("#some_id")) // Should return 1 DIV 
console.log($(".some_class")) // Should return 1 DIV and 1 IMG 
console.log($("input#some_id")) // Should return an empty array 
console.log($("div#some_id.some_class")) // Should return 1 DIV 
console.log($("div.some_class#some_id")) // Should return 1 DIV
```

```html
<div></div>
<div id="some_id" class="some_class some_other_class"></div>
<img id="some_other_id" class="some_class some_other_class"></img>
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Since they asked about perfs, you may want to use a [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker) instead, which is still the fastest way to walk a DOMTree (no recursion). `$ = (selector) => {
  const walker = document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, null);
  const nodes = [];
  while(walker.nextNode()) { if(walker.currentNode.matches(selector)) { nodes.push(walker.currentNode) } }
  return nodes;
}`

Comment: Always return the NodeFilter enums (FILTER_ACCEPT), returning booleans will create issues with some DOM structure (e.g searching `"#references-pane-table"` [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/) will fail on Chrome, for I'm not sure what reasons...). But anyway doing the filtering in the while loop like I did in my first comment is actually (and surprisingly) twice faster than in the NodeFilter function.

Comment: Thanks, I see you're using passing `null` instead of omitting the argument altogether. It looks like the [standard](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-traversal-filter) says that only a value of `null` defaults to `FILTER_ACCEPT`, but MDN says the argument is completely optional (and accepts by default). `null` is probably safer

Comment: Yes I think I had issues with old IE, and got that habit of always passing `null`.